# How to set up chef workstation without that being a chef client itself

Tags: chef-infra, bootstrapping

I seem to be hassling when it comes to chef terminologies. Most of the tutorials assume users are already familiar with the terminologies. Following one of them I got both chef-client and chefdk. All I wanted to do was to be able to setup the work station and bootstrap a node one.

Here is my setup:

- workstation : ubuntu 14.04 laptop (no intention of it being a client) a
- hosted chef account: I subscribed for the 5 nodes account 3 VMs on a
- hosting that I want to control and use to see chef in action

with reading here and there I figured I needed the following:

- client.rb : up to now have no idea how to get it and what it does
- knife.rb: copied from the startup kip to /etc/chef/ (it only looks for it there)
- username.pem : I guess for the authentication somewhere between workstation and chef hosted :server or so
- organization-validation.pem : I guess for the authentication between nodes and the server.

So I put knife.rb ,username.pem and validation.pem(renamed organization-validation.pem) under `/etc/chef` . I also added to my `~/.bash_profile` the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
PATH=$PATH:/opt/chefdk/bin
export PATH
```

So when running my bootstrap command :

```
knife bootstrap server1.domain.com -x user -P pass -N server1 

##knife bootstrap output

WARNING: No knife configuration file found
Connecting to server1.domain.com
server1.domain.com Starting first Chef Client run...
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:02+00:00] WARN: 
server1.domain.com SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
server1.domain.com encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
server1.domain.com attacks.
server1.domain.com To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:
server1.domain.com   # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
server1.domain.com   ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer
server1.domain.com   # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
server1.domain.com   verify_api_cert true
server1.domain.com To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the
server1.domain.com `knife ssl check` command like so:
server1.domain.com   knife ssl check -c /etc/chef/client.rb
server1.domain.com Starting Chef Client, version 11.16.4
server1.domain.com Creating a new client identity for logsmanager using the validator key.
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:04+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to  https://localhost/clients, retry 1/5
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:09+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/clients, retry 2/5
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:14+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/clients, retry 3/5
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:19+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/clients, retry 4/5
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:24+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://localhost/clients, retry 5/5
server1.domain.com Network Error:
server1.domain.com There was a network error connecting to the Chef Server:
server1.domain.com Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to   https://localhost/clients, giving up
server1.domain.com Relevant Config Settings:
server1.domain.com chef_server_url  "https://localhost:443"
server1.domain.com If your chef_server_url is correct, your network could be down.
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:29+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
server1.domain.com Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 27.268943154 seconds
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:29+00:00] ERROR: Connection refused - Connection  refused connecting to https://localhost/clients, giving up
server1.domain.com [2014-12-16T16:55:29+00:00] FATAL:    Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

It's clear I am lost can anyone kindly put me on the right path. Please . Thank you

**EDIT 1**

below is the knife.rb file

```
# See https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife     configuration options

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "username"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/username.pem"
validation_client_name   "organization-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/organizationname-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/organizationname"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

Comment: please post the content of your knife.rb file.

Comment: The default location in which knife expects to find this file is `~/.chef/knife.rb` - have you tried that to resolve "No knife configuration file found"? It's also trying to use a server url of `https://localhost/clients` but your knife file says `https://api.opscode.com`. It seems like you have more than just 1 problem with your config so it's hard to figure out where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
```

It's not finding your knife.rb file.  As a result, it is using a default config which looks for the chef server at localhost:

```
server1.domain.com chef_server_url  "https://localhost:443"
```

Generally knife.rb is in `~/.chef/knife.rb`, but it should also look in `/etc/chef/knife.rb`.  Perhaps you have a permissions issue?  In any case, I'd move it to the standard `~/.chef/knife.rb`

Comment: you may set an environment variable too: `export KNIFE_HOME=/path/to/knife_conf_directory` quite usefull when you work with multiples chef server from the same workstation.

Answer (score -1):

Add a entry of your Chef server into the `/etc/hosts` file of your node.